# Multiple QnA makers on one azure app service

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-services, azure-app-service-plans, azure-qna-maker

I would like to create multiple knowledge bases using https://www.qnamaker.ai. On the UI when I create a new qnamaker service using my azure subscription it actually creates 3 things/services for 1 qnamaker which are as follows

qnamaker as Cognitive service
Azure app service to provision qnamaker
Azure Search service to power qnamaker search

Based on the documentation it makes sense to have this created. But, I would like to see if it's possible to combine all qnamaker's on one single strong , highly scaled azure app service. ?

Comment: Any update on this ?

Answer (score 0):

You are able to create multiple knowledgebases on one Azure app service.

The only thing you would need to change if using APIs is the knowledgebase ID while the subscription key would remain the same.

You can either create new knowledgebases using its API here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/qnamaker/quickstarts/create-new-kb-csharp

Or log into their QnA Portal https://www.qnamaker.ai/ into my knowledgebases, creating a new one and adding in the HTTP Request info to the API method. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/qnamaker/how-to/metadata-generateanswer-usage

Comment: The problem with this option is that you cannot then set different access levels to the different knowledge bases. This used to be available in the QnA Maker preview version but got removed.